Evaluating $\lim_{x\to-\infty}⁡ \frac{\sqrt{9x^2-11x+1}+ \sqrt{4x^2-13x+3}}{x}$

Find the value of
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}⁡ \frac{\sqrt{9x^2-11x+1}+ \sqrt{4x^2-13x+3}}{x}$$

Here's my solution:
$$\frac{x\sqrt{9 - \frac{11}{x} + \frac{1}{x^2}} + x \sqrt{4- \frac{13}{x}+ \frac{3}{x^2}}}{x}$$
Since $x$ tends to $-\infty$, only $9$ and $4$ respectively will be inside the roots and rest variables will become $0$.
Now we have left with $(3x+2x)/x$, which makes $5$. But the correct answer is $-5$.
Where am I mistaken?
What will be the correct steps?
One of the answers says that i should consider -x but any specific reason to consider this since there were no other conditions in the question.
This question was a single option correct so the only correct answer is -5.
Also I apologize about the fact that I'm writing these in words. I'm new here.

That's the second question your posting in a few minutes, and in both of them, you're not showing your word. Here the problem may be that for $x<0$, $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$, so when you want to "factor out" $x$ in the square root, be carful for the signs.

Welcome to Math.SE! ... I formatted your question; please double-check that it matches your intention. ... Also, please include your work. It may be easier (and more helpful to you) for someone to spot a simple sign error in your logic than to work through the problem from scratch. (My suspicion: You overlooked the fact that $x$ is heading for negative infinity, which makes the denominator negative while the numerator is positive.) ... Good luck!

oh thanks for the replies

Thanks for showing your work! (+1) Again, I have formatted your math, so double-check. (BTW: It tends to be better to have key expressions surrounded by $$...$$ instead of $...$ so that they get displayed nicely centered and slightly larger, which improves readability.)

To avoid the error you may subsitute $x=-t$ and get $\lim_{t\to\infty}{\sqrt{9t^2+11t+1}+\sqrt{4t^2+13t+3}\over -t}$

As noticed, since $x$ is eventually negative we have that $\sqrt{x^2}=-x>0$, as an alternative, to avoid this kind of confusion let convert the limit by $y=-x\to \infty$ such that eventually $\sqrt{y^2}=y$ and then
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}⁡ \frac{\sqrt{9x^2-11x+1}+ \sqrt{4x^2-13x+3}}{x}=\lim_{y\to \infty}⁡ \frac{\sqrt{9y^2+11y+1}+ \sqrt{4y^2+13y+3}}{-y}=$$
$$=\lim_{y\to \infty}⁡\frac{y\sqrt{9 + \frac{11}{y} + \frac{1}{y^2}} + y \sqrt{4+ \frac{13}{y}+ \frac{3}{y^2}}}{-y}=-5$$

You are overlooking that $~\displaystyle \sqrt{x^2} = | ~x ~|,~$ rather than $~x,~$ and that for any $~x < 0,~$ you have that
$$\frac{| ~x ~|}{x} = -1.$$

You're forgetting that $x$ is negative (since approaching negative infinity) while √ is positive, so you made a sign error.
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}⁡ \frac{\sqrt{9x^2-11x+1}+ \sqrt{4x^2-13x+3}}{x}$$
$$= \lim_{x\to-\infty}⁡ \frac{\sqrt{9x^2}+ \sqrt{4x^2}}{x}$$
$$= \lim_{x\to-\infty}⁡ \frac{3|x| + 2|x|}{x}$$
$$= \lim_{x\to-\infty}⁡ \frac{5(-x)}{x}$$
$$= -5$$
